# Regex remove including start en end char

Tags: c#, url, .net-core, regexp-replace

I need to remove the "<www.google.com/>" part from "www.google.com<www.google.com/>"
some regex experts here?

BR

solution from someone

Comment: `Regex.Remove("<.*/>$", "");`

Comment: What you ask doesn't require a regex. That's why it's always important to show your own efforts. Not only because it's appreciated if you actually tried something but mainly because such efforts tend to rectify a lot that's not asked clearly.

Comment: But why regex in this case, you need to tell that.

Comment: It is not clear whether you want to remove only this specific string or whether you want to remove any URL in enclosed in `<` and `/>` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "www.google.com<www.google.com/>";
var result = Regex.Replace(s, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
```